# How to clear h:inputText in JSF when I click radio button?

Tags: jsp, jsf, ajax4jsf

How to clear `h:inputText` in JSF when I click radio button?

I have tried the following code

```
if(isExisting.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
{
    t.setValue(""); 
}
```

If radio button's bean value is N then set empty string in the textbox bean value.

I even tried

```
t.setValue(null);
```

But it doesn't clear the textbox on click of radio button.

```
<td width="25%" align="left" class="content_row">
  <h:selectOneRadio id="existingLARB" value="#{LABB.LAOpr.tDetails.isExisting}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{LABB.LAOpr.yesNoList}" />
    <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="existingDetails,existingDetailsLA" action="#{LABB.showExistingDetails}"></a4j:support>
  </h:selectOneRadio>
</td>
```

Comment: can't you just add an id on your radiobutton and create a jQuery-script where you add an click-event to the radiobutton and clear the textbox?

Comment: Please show your xhtml code

Comment: Where's the `<h:inputText>` in the code?